# Why I can not echo mysql query result when using WHERE statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the next code which shows no results:

```
<?php include ("access.php");
$corpustitle = "Korpus Bilingüe Alemany-Català (de)";
$result = mysqli_query($dbiac, "SELECT corpus FROM corpus_info WHERE title = '$corpustitle'") or die(mysqli_error($dbiac));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
echo $row['corpus']."<br>";
} ?>
```

But if I take the WHERE statement out of the query I get next results:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbiac, "SELECT corpus FROM corpus_info") or die(mysqli_error($dbiac));
```

- banctraddeucat_ca
- banctraddeucat_de
- banctraddeuspa_de
- ...etc.

And also if I do the original query at the phpmyadmin I get the result I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: I'm noticing accented characters.Is your DB, IDE, PHP files, HTML, basically everything character encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: try this '$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);'

Comment: Are you sure, that your query is receiving the title, and not just $corpustitle as a string?

Comment: On @delboy1978uk's comment: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: also, missing " from your statement where "WHERE" is taken out

Comment: Instead of running the query, try to `echo` the query in your php script and you will see did script print normally `special characters` that you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after @delboy1978uk comments I added this line before the query, and that made the difference:

```
mysqli_set_charset($dbiac, 'utf8');
```

So the entire code now is:

```
<?php include ("access.php");
$corpustitle = "Korpus Bilingüe Alemany-Català (de)";
mysqli_set_charset($dbiac, 'utf8');
$result = mysqli_query($dbiac, "SELECT corpus FROM corpus_info WHERE title = '$corpustitle'") or die(mysqli_error($dbiac));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
echo $row['corpus']."<br>";
} ?>
```

Thanks...